# How can i override placeOrder() action in Magento 2

Tags: magento, module

I'm newbie in Magento. My shop should work with a web service. I have to check availability of products from web service before magento creates a new order. And after creating order successful i have to send the orderId back to web service. All this actions should be execute when a customer confirm a button "place order".

[image]

In a picture you see an "Place Order". I not sure how Magento does create a new order. I assume that an action placeOrder() will be call. My aim is to put a method checkAvailability() before this action and and method sendOrderId() after this action. checkAvailability() and SendOrderId() are the methods from webservice.

Has somebody an idea, how and where can i do that?

Sorry about bad english. Thank you

Comment: Hi Raymond, I did't write any code now. I don't know where to do that. i have edit my question with an image. maybe can you understand me better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you need to used this event.

1. Used this event observer to check `checkAvailability()`

   `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`
2. Used this event observer to used `SendOrderId()`

   `sales_order_place_after`

Comment: Thx Dhiren, I have create an observer event in my module. That shold be override checkout_onepage_controller_success_action. Do you know how can I do something like checkAvailability() -> if "true" call a default checkout_onepage_controller_success_action and if "false" go back to cart. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you ask new question for this, So other can also answer if know.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to overwrite a function instead a class method (I used to overwrite Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order).

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                'My_Module/js/action/place-order': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

place-order.js

```
define(['mage/utils/wrapper'], function (wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (placeOrderAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(placeOrderAction, function (originalAction, paymentData, redirectOnSuccess) {
            // my own code here
            return originalAction(paymentData, redirectOnSuccess);
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. I needed to override placeOrder action that was announced in third part  module (*Amasty_Checkout*).

So, my solution was to create mixin in my theme.

1) Announce the mixin in theme with `myTheme/Amasty_Checkout/requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Amasty_Checkout/js/view/onepage': {
                'Amasty_Checkout/js/view/onepage-extend': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

2) Add mixin `myTheme/Amasty_Checkout/web/js/view/onepage-extend.js` with code:

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Amasty_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Amasty_Checkout/js/model/agreement-validator',
    'Amasty_Checkout/js/model/agreement-validator-old',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'Amasty_Checkout/js/model/amalert',
    'mage/translate'
],
function (
    $,
    Component,
    ko,
    registry,
    quote,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    checkoutValidator,
    checkoutValidatorOld,
    additionalValidators,
    alert,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {

        placeOrder: function () {
            // Here you put your extended code
        }
    };

    return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../default returns.
        return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive
    };
});
```

Note that in my case I copied all content in define[...] section from original module script (`'Amasty_Checkout/js/view/onepage'`) that I needed to override.

Here is the resource that helped me with my solution https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1864#issuecomment-141112927

I hope this will help someone save time.